# Convert rectangular equation $(x^2+y^2)^2 - 4(x^2-y^2) = 0$ to polar form

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametric

So I am not sure how to do this problem : "Convert rectangular equation $(x^2+y^2)^2 - 4(x^2-y^2) = 0$ to polar form". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **HINT:** Recall that $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$ (moreover, $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, which can be handy)

Answer (score 3):

$$0=(x^2+y^2)^2 - 4(x^2-y^2) $$
Recall that $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$

$$  0=(r^2)^2-4(r^2 \cos^2(\theta)-r^2\sin^2(\theta))$$

$$ 0=r^4-4(r^2(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))$$

$$ 0 = r^4-4r^2\cos(2\theta)$$

$$ 0 = r^2(r^2-4\cos(2\theta))$$

Comment: you can go further!

Comment: @Arnaldo Oh I thought the zero was an "O"...

Comment: @Arnaldo is it r = sqrt(4cos(2theta))

Comment: @Nahian: you can leave like the answer or you can split in $r=0$ or what you suggested.